# how to concatenate strings in #include statement

Tags: c++, macros, string-concatenation, stringification

How do I concatenate two strings in an include statement?

I tried the code below - and also without `##` - but both times, only the `BASE_DIR` part was output by the preprocessor.

```
#define BASE_DIR    "../Source/micropython/" /* Assume this file is in ATI_micropython/Headers */

#include BASE_DIR##"py/parse.h"

#include BASE_DIR ## "py/gc.h"
#include BASE_DIR ## "py/mpstate.h"
```

Comment: @Ron ok. How do I do that?

Comment: @Ron I tried `#include BASE_DIR+"py/gc.h"` but it was a compiler error

Comment: This sounds like an over-complex solution.Can you not just conditionally include one set of headers or a different set based on a macro?

Comment: @Galik I've been integrating a 3rd party library and having this very issue.

Comment: In fact this specific problem looks like what the *include root* compiler flags are designed to solve. `-I` on `GCC` not sure what `VC` uses

Comment: @Galik how do I mark my question as duplicate?